# sumar los valores de mi select y me los muestre en el total ya sumados

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

Hola tengo problemas con mi código, al momento de mostrar el resultado no me lo `suma` y me muestra los números juntos `sin sumarlos`, y también si me podrían ayudar en saber como al momento de yo seleccionar un select este aparezca en el total y conforme yo vaya seleccionando el siguiente select, este se vaya sumando gracias y me ayudarían mucho.
Aqui les dejo mi `codigo`, espero y me puedan ayudar....

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <form name="sumar">

        <p type="text-align" name="etiqueta1" class="etiqueta1"> Opciónes de impresión </p>

        <label>Tipo</label> <br>
        <select name="list1" class="list1">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
            <option value="100">SIN suaje/pestaña (22.5 x 29.2 cm)</option>
        </select>
        <br>

        <label>Cantidad</label> <br>
        <select name="list2" class="list2">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
            <option value="20">25</option>
            <option value="40">50</option>
            <option value="80">100</option>
            <option value="120">200</option>
            <option value="160">300</option>
            <option value="300">500</option>
        </select>
        <br>

        <label>Impresión</label> <br>
        <select name="list3" class="list3">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
            <option value="50">4/0 (Color solo frente)</option>
            <option value="100">4/4 (Color frente y vuelta)</option>
        </select>
        <br>

        <label>Tipo de papel</label> <br>
        <select name="list4" class="list4">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
            <option value="200">Coché 300 g</option>
            <option value="300">Cartulina sulfatada 12 pts 1 cara</option>
        </select>
        <br>

        <p type="text-align" name="etiqueta1" class="etiqueta1">  Terminados </p>

        <label>Plastificado frente y vuelta</label> <br>
        <select name="list5" class="list5">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
            <option value="150">Delgado brillante (BOPP)</option>
            <option value="300">Delgado mate (BOPP)</option>
        </select>
        <br>

        <label>Esquinas redondeadas (con datos de contacto hacia arriba)</label> <br>
        <select name="list6" class="list6">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
            <option value="0">Ninguna</option>
            <option value="80">4</option>
        </select>
        <br> <br>
        
        <label>Total</label>
        <input type="text" name="total">

    </form>

    <script>
        var numero3, numero1, numero2, numero4, numero5, numero6;
    caja = document.forms["sumar"].elements;

    $(".list1").change(function() {
      numero1 = caja["list1"].value;
      mostrar();
    });
    
    $(".list2").change(function() {
      numero2 = caja["list2"].value;
      mostrar();
    });

    $(".list3").change(function() {
      numero3 = caja["list3"].value;
      mostrar();
    });

    $(".list4").change(function() {
      numero4 = caja["list4"].value;
      mostrar();
    });

    $(".list5").change(function() {
      numero5 = caja["list5"].value;
      mostrar();
    });

    $(".list6").change(function() {
      numero6 = caja["list6"].value;
      mostrar();
    });


    function mostrar() {
        if (numero1 >= 0 && numero2 >= 0 && numero3 >= 0 && numero4 >= 0 && numero5 >= 0 && numero6 >= 0) {
            var resultado = 0;
            resultado = (numero1 + numero2 + numero3 + numero4 + numero5 + numero6);
            caja["total"].value = (resultado);  
        }
    }

    </script>

</body>
</html>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltó hacer un `parseFloat()` al asignar los valores de los inputs a las variables, pero depende de lo que requieras puedes usar también un `parseInt()`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <form name="sumar">

        <p type="text-align" name="etiqueta1" class="etiqueta1"> Opciónes de impresión </p>

        <label>Tipo</label> <br>
        <select name="list1" class="list1">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
            <option value="100">SIN suaje/pestaña (22.5 x 29.2 cm)</option>
        </select>
        <br>

        <label>Cantidad</label> <br>
        <select name="list2" class="list2">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
            <option value="20">25</option>
            <option value="40">50</option>
            <option value="80">100</option>
            <option value="120">200</option>
            <option value="160">300</option>
            <option value="300">500</option>
        </select>
        <br>

        <label>Impresión</label> <br>
        <select name="list3" class="list3">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
            <option value="50">4/0 (Color solo frente)</option>
            <option value="100">4/4 (Color frente y vuelta)</option>
        </select>
        <br>

        <label>Tipo de papel</label> <br>
        <select name="list4" class="list4">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
            <option value="200">Coché 300 g</option>
            <option value="300">Cartulina sulfatada 12 pts 1 cara</option>
        </select>
        <br>

        <p type="text-align" name="etiqueta1" class="etiqueta1">  Terminados </p>

        <label>Plastificado frente y vuelta</label> <br>
        <select name="list5" class="list5">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
            <option value="150">Delgado brillante (BOPP)</option>
            <option value="300">Delgado mate (BOPP)</option>
        </select>
        <br>

        <label>Esquinas redondeadas (con datos de contacto hacia arriba)</label> <br>
        <select name="list6" class="list6">
            <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Seleccine...</option>
            <option value="0">Ninguna</option>
            <option value="80">4</option>
        </select>
        <br> <br>
        
        <label>Total</label>
        <input type="text" name="total">

    </form>

    <script>
        var numero3 = 0, numero1 = 0, numero2 = 0, numero4 = 0, numero5 = 0, numero6 = 0;
    caja = document.forms["sumar"].elements;

    $(".list1").change(function() {
      numero1 = parseFloat(caja["list1"].value);
      mostrar();
    });
    
    $(".list2").change(function() {
      numero2 = parseFloat(caja["list2"].value);
      mostrar();
    });

    $(".list3").change(function() {
      numero3 = parseFloat(caja["list3"].value);
      mostrar();
    });

    $(".list4").change(function() {
      numero4 = parseFloat(caja["list4"].value);
      mostrar();
    });

    $(".list5").change(function() {
      numero5 = parseFloat(caja["list5"].value);
      mostrar();
    });

    $(".list6").change(function() {
      numero6 = parseFloat(caja["list6"].value);
      mostrar();
    });


    function mostrar() {
        if (numero1 >= 0 && numero2 >= 0 && numero3 >= 0 && numero4 >= 0 && numero5 >= 0 && numero6 >= 0) {
            var resultado = 0;
            resultado = (numero1 + numero2 + numero3 + numero4 + numero5 + numero6);
            caja["total"].value = (resultado);  
        }
    }

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me respondiste todas mis dudas, te agradezco mucho.